# What does it take to brute force 42 hex characters

Tags: brute-force, hardware, decryption

What does it take to brute force something like this

```
00f54a5851e9372b87810a8e60cdd2e7cfd80b6e31
```

I can brute force anything else like

```
iambad, blackapple1, etc
```

But how can I brute force something like that line? And what is the best hardware to do that?

Comment: Length is king when it comes to brute force of random data. 128 bits of randomness is impossible to brute force.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does it take to brute force something like this
> 00f54a5851e9372b87810a8e60cdd2e7cfd80b6e31

What you have shown above is 42 hex characters, which is 21 bytes, which is 168 bits. Therefore, if you know nothing else about the structure of the data, you have 2^168 different possibilities to brute force.

As an illustrative example, suppose that you could leverage the entire peak hash rate of the bitcoin network to try and brute force this hash. Suppose that rate is 200,000,000,000,000,000,000 hashes per second. Or, if you aren't hashing, suppose you have some insanely massive hardware system that can make 200,000,000,000,000,000,000 attempts per second. (Again, this large rate value is just an example of a rate of a very very powerful system--way more powerful than you can afford.)

Even in this pie-in-the-sky example, if would still take you about 60 billion trillion years to brute force the 21 byte value. So, effectively, it is impossible.

> I can brute force anything else like
> iambad, blackapple1, etc

The first example is just six lower case letters. If you are restricted to six lowercase letter, then there are only 26^6 possibilities. As you can easily check, 26^6 is way way fewer than 2^168. Similarly, in your second case, if you know that "blackapple1" always follows the pattern of: dictionary-word+dictionary-word+single-integer then there are only about nine billion possibilities to brute force. Again, as you can easily check, nine billion is way way fewer possibilities than 2^168.

> But how can I brute force something like that line?

As discussed above, effectively, you can not.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. 32 hex characters is `16^32`, which is equal to `2^128`.

128 bits is impossible to brute-force with any hardware that exists today (and that is unlikely to change in the near future).

**Edit**: OP has changed the question to 42 hex chars, which equals 168 bits. That's even more impossible.

Comment: He's showing 42 hex characters, not 32. But, anyways, it is still impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you are answering the question in the *title* of the post, which is different from the body of the post.